# What are the advantages of using Google Cloud Endpoints, explained in non-technical terms with examples?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have previously used

```
@app.route('/mypage/<int:myvariable>/')
```

to create rules for what should happen when users land on different urls on my website. I have done this on local machines that have been running on my own virtual servers.

Now I am learning to publish my first web app to Google App Engine. I have heard that I should be using Google Cloud Endpoints instead of the route decorator.

```
@endpoints...
```

I've read a few articles about endpoints and some of the benefits of endpoints that they list are:

- Endpoints makes it easier to create a web backend for web clients and mobile clients
- Endpoints free you from having to write wrappers to handle communication with App Engine

Even if I have read this I can't wrap my head around what this means. I don't understand it. Can you explain in non-technical terms with examples what the advantages of using `@endpoints` is compared to alternatives? The alternative that I am familiar with is `@app.route`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints can be thought of as a subset of `@app.route`. They are intended to solve the API backend problem for mobile and javascript clients. They are not intended to serve web pages and other hypermedia. You can use the normal routing methods of your framework of choice to create a web service for your application but Google Cloud Endpoints takes care of a lot of boilerplate for you.

There are a lot of limitations with Google Cloud Endpointsso be sure to familiarize yourself with them before committing. For one, you cannot host Google Cloud Endpoints on a custom domain name. They are only accessible via `<app_id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/*`

Comment: Do you mean that I can't show content I create with google endpoints on www.mydomainname.com?

Comment: If you have an endpoint located at `/_ah/api/<service>/<version>/users` and a custom domain name `example.org`, you cannot access `http://example.org/_ah/api/<service>/<version>/users`, only `http://<project_id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/<service>/<version>/users`.  See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384 Cloud Endpoints are for creating Web Service APIs, not for serving traditionally formatted content. You should probably read the documentation a bit so you understand what it was designed for. https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/

Answer (score 2):

> Endpoints makes it easier to create a web backend for web clients and
>   mobile clients

What this means is that you can create one backend and then iOS, Android and Web-apps (via Javascript for example), can execute your API methods with specific client generated libraries.

This is convenient if you are building a backend that you want to be easily accessed via smartphones or through a web browser.

> Endpoints free you from having to write wrappers to handle
>   communication with App Engine

With Endpoints you can generate client libraries (e.g. Android, iOS, Javascript) that you can then execute your API methods. You don't have to worry about writing a bunch of additional code to do that.

My Opinion:
I have never used Cloud Endpoints to make a web-app but it is very convenient if you are making a mobile app for iOS and Android because you can access your backend with both platforms.

One reason you might want to use Cloud Endpoints for a web-app instead of something else is because of [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/). Datastore is the way Cloud Endpoints stores data. It is a NoSQL storage method which is kinda tricky to wrap your head around at first if you come from a relational database background, but once you get it, it makes a lot of sense.